# Python: Convert table to string to key:value pairs and store in nested dict using comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I received data from a subprocess command as a string. I want to store this data in a nested dict using dictionary comprehension. How do I do this? Note: Table rows and columns will vary for each subprocess command.

This is only an example: (I have returned this as a string from subprocess.)

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop1     7:1    0  89.3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
sda       8:0    0    11G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  10.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Here is the output I want:

```
{block device 1: 
    { "name" :  value,
    "maj:min" : value,
    "RM" : value,
    "SIZE" : value,
    "RO": value,
    "TYPE": value,
    "MOUNTPOINT" : value},
 block device 2: 
     { "name" :  value,
    "maj:min" : value,
    "RM" : value,
    "SIZE" : value,
    "RO": value,
    "TYPE": value,
    "MOUNTPOINT" : value},
...
}
```

Here is the method I am using to sort this (it's nasty, I know).

```
def multiple_column_dict(a_string, cat):

    lines = re.split("\n", a_string)
    keys = re.split(" +", lines[0])

    values1 = re.split(" +", lines[1])
    values2 = re.split(" +", lines[2])
    values3 = re.split(" +", lines[3])
    values4 = re.split(" +", lines[4])
    values5 = re.split(" +", lines[5])
    values6 = re.split(" +", lines[6])

    a_dict1 = dict(zip(keys, values1))
    a_dict2 = dict(zip(keys, values2))
    a_dict3 = dict(zip(keys, values3))
    a_dict4 = dict(zip(keys, values4))
    a_dict5 = dict(zip(keys, values5))
    a_dict6 = dict(zip(keys, values6))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = """
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop1     7:1    0  89.3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
sda       8:0    0    11G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  10.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
"""

header = ["NAME", "MAJ:MIN", "RM", "SIZE", "RO", "TYPE", "MOUNTPOINT"]

result = [dict(zip(header, values))
          for line in data.split("\n")[2:]
          if line
          for values in [line.split()]]

print(result)
```

Which would yield

```
[
 {'NAME': 'loop0', 'MAJ:MIN': '7:0', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '140.7M', 'RO': '1', 'TYPE': 'loop', 'MOUNTPOINT': '/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82'},
 {'NAME': 'loop1', 'MAJ:MIN': '7:1', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '89.3M', 'RO': '1', 'TYPE': 'loop', 'MOUNTPOINT': '/snap/core/6673'},
 {'NAME': 'sda', 'MAJ:MIN': '8:0', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '11G', 'RO': '0', 'TYPE': 'disk'},
 {'NAME': '├─sda1', 'MAJ:MIN': '8:1', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '10.9G', 'RO': '0', 'TYPE': 'part', 'MOUNTPOINT': '/'},
 {'NAME': '├─sda14', 'MAJ:MIN': '8:14', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '4M', 'RO': '0', 'TYPE': 'part'},
 {'NAME': '└─sda15', 'MAJ:MIN': '8:15', 'RM': '0', 'SIZE': '106M', 'RO': '0', 'TYPE': 'part', 'MOUNTPOINT': '/boot/efi'}
]
```

Here, we generate a list of dicts.

Comment: Looks like `TYPE` & `MOUNTPOINT` are 2 different keys

Comment: @Rakesh: You were right, I needed to change the `header` array. Thanks for spotting it.